# Root Galaxy S7 edge - KingRoot and knox

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s7

Is it possible to root the Galaxy S7 edge Exynos with KingRoot leaving knox to 0x0?

If not KingRoot there are other ways? (Not CF-auto-root as the knox bit will be 0x1)

My model is SM-G935F latest version released, European.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any root method that will work, however there is currently an exploit being refined on XDA for the S7. This is the closest that anyone I've found has gotten, so feel free to follow along:

[No KNOX Exynos root method via engKernel. Exynos testers needed.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/how-to/knox-exynos-root-method-via-engkernel-t3423438/page11)

Comment: This could be put as a comment, it isn't a full answer to the OPs problem

Comment: I think is better an answer 'cause he replied to my questions.. I'll just need to wait (and hope that a future updates will not "accidentally" fix this exploit)